# What does “Sie strich sich über die Stirn” mean?

Tags: meaning

The dictionary entry for streichen seems to have many meanings for the same word, although I don’t see which one would make sense.

Answer (score 6):

"Streichen" in this context means "to wipe". Thus the complete sentence translated to English would be

> She wiped her forehead.

This could be e.g. because she was sweating, she was trying to get her hair out of her face, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this context "to wipe" is the correct translation, as in "She wiped over her forehead" Other usual use cases and translations for "streichen" are:

- **to cancel/delete/remove:** e.g. "to cancel financial support" => "finanzielle Unterstützung streichen
- **to paint:** e.g. "to paint a wall" => "eine Wand streichen" **note:** "to paint a painting" => "ein Gemälde ***malen***"